# Javascript incorrect? Page resets

Tags: javascript, html

Ok I have issue that is confusing me.  I have a registration page that I made up for a project, and each time I enter the information it is supposed to store it in a cookie.  I watched after the first time and saw the information in the bar, but it would not pass to the login page.

Here is the HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 

Project (Register.html)
 Author: Michael R. Mastro II
 Date: 06 Jun 2015
-->
    <title>Registration Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */

    /* ]]> */
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:red">
    <form action = "" id="aboutForm" method="get" 
            enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            onsubmit="confirmSubmit();"
            onreset="return confirmReset();">
        <h2 style="text-align:center; color:white">Pizzeria Registration Page</h2>
            <p style="color:white">User Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" size="50" value="Enter Username" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Username') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Username';}" /></p>
            <p style="color:white">Street Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="sAdd" id="sAdd" size="50" value="Enter Street Address" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Street Address') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Street Address';}" /></p>
            <p style="color:white">City, State, Zip:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30" value="Enter City" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter City') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter City';}" /><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="state" id="state" size="10" maxlength="3" value="Enter State" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter State') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter State';}" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="zipCode" id="zipCode" size="20" maxlength="10" value="Enter Zip Code" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Zip Code') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Zip Code';}" /><br /><br /></p>
            <p style="color:white">Email Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" size="50" value="Enter Email Address" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Email Address') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Email Address';}" /></p>
            <p style="color:white">Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="50" /><br /><br />
            Confirm Password:&nbsp;<input type="password" name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm" size="50" onblur="confirmPassword();" /><br /><br /></p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
            </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

and here is the JavaScript:

```
function registerForm() {
            var userName = document.getElementById( 'userName' ).value;
            var sAdd = document.getElementById( 'sAdd' ).value;
            var city = document.getElementById( 'city' ).value;
            var state = document.getElementById( 'state' ).value;
            var zip = document.getElementById( 'zipCode' ).value;
            var emailAddress = document.getElementById( 'emailAddress' ).value;
            var password = document.getElementById( 'password' ).value;
            var regDate = new Date();
            regDate.setFullYear(regDate.getFullYear() + 1);
            document.cookie = "username=" + encodeURIComponent(userName) + "; expires=" + regDate.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = "street=" + encodeURIComponent(sAdd) + "; expires=" + regDate.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = "city=" + encodeURIComponent(city) + "; expires=" + regDate.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = "state=" + encodeURIComponent(state) + "; expires=" + regDate.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = "zip=" + encodeURIComponent(zip) + "; expires=" + regDate.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = "emailAddress=" + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + "; expires=" + regDate.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = "password=" + encodeURIComponent(password) + "; expires=" + regDate.toUTCString();
            window.alert("Thank you for registering!");
            close.this();
        }

        function confirmSubmit(){
        //This function will validate that all the fields are filled in.  It will also
        //check that the email address is a valid form of email address.  If a box is not
        //valid, then it sets the focus on that field.

            //This will verify the username field has been filled out
            if( document.getElementById( 'userName' ).value == "Enter Username" 
            || document.getElementById( 'userName' ).value == "" ){
                alert( "You must enter a username" );
                document.getElementById( 'userName' ).focus();
                return false;
            }  // end userName if statement

            //This will verify that the username is not already in use
            if(document.cookie.length == 0){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                var savedData = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
                var dataArray = savedData.split("; ");
                var storedName;
                for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; ++i) {
                    if (dataArray[i].substring(0,dataArray[i].indexOf("="))== "username") {
                        storedName = dataArray[i].substring(dataArray[i].indexOf("=") + 1,dataArray[i].length);
                    }
                }
                if( document.getElementById( 'userName' ).value == storedName ){
                    alert("Username already being used, please choose another Username");
                }
                return false;
            }

            //This will verify the street address field has been filled out
            if( document.getElementById( 'sAdd' ).value == "Enter Street Address" 
            || document.getElementById( 'sAdd' ).value == "" ){
                alert( "You must enter a street address" );
                document.getElementById( 'sAdd' ).focus();
                return false;
            }  // end sAdd if statement


            //This will verify the city field has been filled out
            if( document.getElementById( 'city' ).value == "Enter City" 
            || document.getElementById( 'city' ).value == "" ){
                alert( "You must enter a city" );
                document.getElementById( 'city' ).focus();
                return false;
            }  // end city if statement


            //This will verify the state field has been filled out
            if( document.getElementById( 'state' ).value == "Enter State" 
            || document.getElementById( 'state' ).value == "" ){
                alert( "You must enter a state" );
                document.getElementById( 'state' ).focus();
                return false;
            }  // end state if statement


            //This will verify the zip code field has been filled out
            if( document.getElementById( 'zipCode' ).value == "Enter Zip Code" 
            || document.getElementById( 'zipCode' ).value == "" ){
                alert( "You must enter a zip code" );
                document.getElementById( 'zipCode' ).focus();
                return false;
            }  // end zipCode if statement


            //This will verify the email Address field has been filled out
            if( document.getElementById( 'emailAddress' ).value == "Enter Email Address" 
            || document.getElementById( 'emailAddress' ).value == "" ){
                alert( "You must enter a email address" );
                document.getElementById( 'emailAddress' ).focus();
                return false;
            }  // end emailAddress if statement

            var emailPattern = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
            var email = document.getElementById( 'emailAddress' ).value;
            if( !email.match(emailPattern) ){
                alert( "You must enter a valid email address" );
                document.getElementById( 'emailAddress' ).focus();
                return false;
            }

            //This will verify the password field has been filled out
            if( document.getElementById( 'password' ).value == "" ){
                alert( "You must enter a password" );
                document.getElementById( 'password' ).focus();
                return false;
            }  // end password if statement

            var submitForm = window.confirm( "Are you sure you want to submit the form?" );
            if( submitForm == true )
                return registerForm();
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }  // end confirmSubmit function

        function confirmReset(){
            var resetForm = window.confirm( "Are you sure you want to reset the form?" );
            if( resetForm == true )
                return true;
            return false;
        }  // end confirmReset function

        function confirmPassword(){
        //Function should check to see if the two passwords entered are the same..
        //if they are not, pop up an alert and set the focus back to password
            var password = document.getElementById( 'password' ).value;
            var password_confirm = document.getElementById( 'password_confirm' ).value;
            if( password != password_confirm ){
                alert("Passwords do not match.");
                document.getElementById( 'password' ).value = "";
                document.getElementById( 'password_confirm' ).value = "";
                document.getElementById( 'password' ).focus();
            }  // end if statement
        }  // end confirmPassword function
```

It is supposed to return to the login page, but it will not head back there.  Any thoughts?

Comment: why u are not using Jquery solution? for cookies in javascript, you need to do extra work. If you are interested in Jquery solution then let me know plus edit ur question by adding jQUERY tag

Comment: Perhaps a fiddle would help us assist you?

Comment: @MikeMastro check my answer. javascript solution

Comment: I think you missed the "the shortest code necessary to reproduce" part of the guidelines.

Comment: well I narrowed down the issue a little bit after trying the solution below.  That hadn't worked, because it was not creating the cookie.  The issues seems to lie in the validation of the username from the cookie.  Where it is the if statement of //This will verify that the username is not already in use.  I commented it out and it got to the confirmation.  I am trying to check that if there is a cookie, that the username in question is not used.  If there is not a cookie, let it continue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save cookie using path=/ . otherwise your cookie will only be accessible by your current page(where you are writing a cookie). Use following

```
 document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2015 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```